# Center a div in the screen regardless of origin

Tags: css, css-position

I have a lot of divs **in a flexbox** and when I click on one, I want it to scale up and then center itself in the viewport regardless of where it started (row/col). I have tried this with the typical "center a div" code, but its positioning is not even consistent across each div in the flexbox, let alone in the center. I am not completely against using JS, but I feel that there must be a pure CSS way to do this. Current attempt:

```css
.selector {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) scale(2);
}
```

which leads to any div being scaled up and moved to the right of its starting position.
Is there a way, or is JS my only option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important addition would be `position: fixed` to have it centered in the viewport/window, regardless of the HTML structure. And change `translate(-50%, 0)` to `translate(-50%, -50%)`, otherwise it won't get centered vertically:

```
.selector {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that works! I forgot that I had set them to relative earlier.